# using collapsing Toolbar with tabhost

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am using a Toolbar that is collapsible and a Tabhost having 3 tabs. But unfortunately, the Tabhost is overlaying the Toolbar. I want the Tabhost just below the Toolbar.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.chandra.user.newstrailerapp.app;

import android.app.LocalActivityManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Toolbar toolbar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    LocalActivityManager mLocalActivityManager = new LocalActivityManager(this, false);
    mLocalActivityManager.dispatchCreate(savedInstanceState);
    tabHost.setup(mLocalActivityManager);



    //RecycleVIew
    RecyclerView recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    //to use RecycleView, you need a layout manager. default is LinearLayoutManager
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    YoutubecardAdapter adapter=new YoutubecardAdapter(MainActivity.this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.chandra.user.newstrailerapp.app.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<TabHost
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/list1">

                </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab2"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/list2">

                </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab3"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/list3">

                </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Also here the screenshot

[Screenshot of MainActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Orc8S.jpg)

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32865957/scrolling-with-collapsing-toolbar-and-tabs

Comment: After adding app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" application crashed.

Comment: Error log is : >java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.chandra.user.newstrailerapp.app/com.chandra.user.newstrailerapp.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(boolean)' on a null object reference, >at com.chandra.user.newstrailerapp.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)

Comment: @ak sacha reply me....

Comment: @ak sacha but I have initialized the same. Check in MainActicity.java

Comment: @ak sacha reply please...

Comment: @aksacha the same error is continuing. I can't understand...

Comment: @aksacha how can I do the initialization of RecyclerView?

Comment: @aksacha please reply?

Comment: Sorry if I disturbed you, but as per you I'm using uninitialized RecyclerView object . So I want to know that, how can I initialise the same?

Comment: @aksacha if you don't mind, will you please reply.

Answer (score 0):

add `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` to your AppBarLayout

and `android:gravity="top"` to your toolbar