# how to show tabs on top in collapsing toolbar while scrolling

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-coordinatorlayout, floating-action-button, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a layout with collapsing toolbar and tabs as shown in attached image below 
[image]

I want to show my tab layout on top  while scrolling the list in anyone of the tabs 
I have tried some links [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32865957/scrolling-with-collapsing-toolbar-and-tabs) and end with below result as shown in image below

[image]

I want to hide my toolbar ,profile image and textview completely while scrolling the list in any tabs 

following is the layout xml code  that I used

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="256dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@color/background_color"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/main.backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/mobilebanner"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/main.toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/user_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:text="abc"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/background_color"
                app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/black" />

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/htab_viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="400dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>



        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/main.appbar"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center_horizontal|center"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:src="@drawable/user" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```